# C# args without a main method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, args, boilerplate, entry-point

I am new to the C# world but have seen other programming languages give access to command-line arguments from places like `main` function/method, `sys.argv`, etc.

It was unusual to see the following statement placed *globally* in the boilerplate ASP.NET Core Web App MVC (Version 6.0) `Program.cs` file of Visual Studio:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Hovering over that parameter inside my IDE does seem to suggest it is indeed `string[] args`, but where is the entry point?

Answer (score 10):

I hope someone brings in further interesting details, but as a minimum, a bit of searching yielded the following result (short answer — **Top-level Statements**) from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line):

> Starting in C# 9, you can omit the `Main` method, and write C# statements as if they were in the `Main` method [...] For information about how to write application code with an implicit entry point method, see [Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements).

The page covering top-level statements makes it more clear:

> ### `args`
>
> Top-level statements can reference the `args` variable to access any command-line arguments that were entered. The `args` variable is never null but its `Length` is zero if no command-line arguments were provided.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Re: `Let's clean up the comment thread then :) I'll delete my comments because they make no sense any more.` Hm, I should have been more precise with my edit summary then (eg., *added more information following [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)'s suggestion in the comments*) for appropriate credit, but I hope this comment captures its gist :)